No map and odom in navigation
I'm trying to do navigation in Ros, but when I run the navigation launch file with the map obtained through slam, it doesn't work properly. When I check the tf tree, the map and odom do not exist as shown below.
enter image description here
I thought that amcl creates map and odom, but I don't know what the problem is. The following is part of my amcl launch file and part of navigation launch file. If anyone know the cause of the problem, can anyone tell me the cause and solution?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried to change AMCL code to publish map but AMCL does not make map and odom.
I need map and odom to publish to base_footprint.
